# Cygwin installation stops in make step

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, gcc

I'm installing Cygwin and GNU C compiler with the help of the tutorial [How to Install the Latest GCC on Windows](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/)

I have completed the following steps

1. Install Cygwin
2. Install Required Cygwin Packages

The 3rd step is "Download, Build and Install the Latest GCC".
I'm stuck when I run the `make -j4` command with the following error in the `Cygwin Terminal`.

```
$ make -j4
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Prasanna Rajaram/build-gcc-6.1.0'
Configuring in ./intl
Configuring in ./libiberty
Configuring in ./lto-plugin
/bin/sh: /home/Prasanna: No such file or directory
Makefile:7416: recipe for target 'configure-libiberty' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-libiberty] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Configuring in ./fixincludes
/bin/sh: /home/Prasanna: No such file or directory
Makefile:5330: recipe for target 'configure-intl' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-intl] Error 1
/bin/sh: /home/Prasanna: No such file or directory
Makefile:9308: recipe for target 'configure-lto-plugin' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-lto-plugin] Error 1
/bin/sh: /home/Prasanna: No such file or directory
Makefile:3470: recipe for target 'configure-fixincludes' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Prasanna Rajaram/build-gcc-6.1.0'
Makefile:879: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also do guess where it has gone wrong. In my home directory path `'/home/Prasanna Rajaram/` there is a space between my first and last name. I don't know how Windows 10 had created a folder name like that, under the `C:\Users` directory.

How can I overcome this problem? I'm reluctant to rename the user directory as one word (like:`PrasannaRajaram`) as this might affect other programs which might use this path.

There is also this thought, that this path may apply only for Cygwin as it starts with `/home`

How can I make this work?

**Edit-1**
After the following the steps from the below answer

```
mkdir /home/prasanna
mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd
sed -i -e "s/Prasanna Rajaram/prasanna/g" /etc/passwd
```

The output on Cygwin now looks like this:

```
$ make -j4
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Prasanna Rajaram/build-gcc-6.1.0'
Configuring in ./lto-plugin
Configuring in ./intl
Configuring in ./fixincludes
/home/Prasanna: /home/Prasanna: is a directory
Makefile:9308: recipe for target 'configure-lto-plugin' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-lto-plugin] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Configuring in ./libiberty
/home/Prasanna: /home/Prasanna: is a directory
Makefile:5330: recipe for target 'configure-intl' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-intl] Error 1
/home/Prasanna: /home/Prasanna: is a directory
Makefile:3470: recipe for target 'configure-fixincludes' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-fixincludes] Error 1
/home/Prasanna: /home/Prasanna: is a directory
Makefile:7416: recipe for target 'configure-libiberty' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-libiberty] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Prasanna Rajaram/build-gcc-6.1.0'
Makefile:879: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-passwdinfo

in short:

```
mkdir /home/prasanna
mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd
sed -i -e "s/Prasanna Rajaram/prasanna/g" /etc/passwd
```

close all  Cygwin Terminal and restart it.

Disclaimer: building gcc is for expert; I suggest you to start with a much simpler project.

**Update from the comments**

1. Once the above steps are completed, move the `build-gcc-6.1.0` and
   `gcc-6.1.0` folders to `/home/prasanna` folder
2. Run the `make -j4` and now (from `/home/prasanna` folder)it should run without any problems

Comment: I completed the steps you suggested. It still gives me the same set of errors

Comment: This one `/bin/sh: /home/Prasanna: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: It is the first error in your log. Is still there or not?

Comment: I will post the new screen shot as **edit**. The answer is **It's gone** now. I didn't notice. Thanks for pointing out. Looks like the right direction !

Comment: You are still using the wrong directory "/home/Prasanna Rajaram/build-gcc-6.1.0" with a space inside. Move the code in another place and restart including the config stage.